# Restoring a multiband Image shape after passing through a Keras Flat layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I have an image containing 6 different bands.

I have pre-processed the image to make it ready for the model as follows:

```
ds1, image = raster.read(imagePath, bands='all')
```

then I reshaped it with pyrsgis

```
image = changeDimension(image)
```

Finally, I split over 255

```
xTrain = xTrain / 255.0
```

and reshape it to be coupled with manually tagged classes

```
image= image.reshape((image.shape[0], 1, image.shape[1]))
```

I am trying to pass the image through an autoencoder that I've built with Keras and has the following structure:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, nBands)),
    keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=l1(10e-6)),
    keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='sigmoid')])
```

The training works well.
When I use `predicted = model.predict(newImg)` I get the predicted array with the shape of (1391808, 6).

But the problem is, I do not know how can I reconstruct the image from the output so I can finally save it.

Comment: what is the output shape would you like to get in the end?

Comment: well autoencoders are supposed to reconstruct the image. I suppose it should be same as the input image? that is a 1056x1318 tif image with 6 bands

Comment: when you pass the input, does the first dimension represent the number of samples?

Comment: you might simply be looking for `tf.keras.layers.Reshape()`

Comment: I managed to save the image with the following:
predicted = predicted[:,1]                                                        


prediction = np.reshape(predicted, (ds3.RasterYSize, ds3.RasterXSize))
raster.export(prediction, ds3, filename=outFile, dtype='float', bands='all')

However, it seems that the image is being saved in black and white (probably because the rest of the bands are lost). Any ideas?

Comment: Multiply it back with 255?

Comment: Noo no. that's not the issue. I believe the issue is that I am losing some bands or information when saving. I reconstructed the image but lost the colors. I will add an answer of how i did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone had the same issue, this was the solution

```
predicted = model.predict(featuresHyderabad)
predictedArr = np.zeros(shape = ( nBands, imageHeight, imageWidth ))
for i in range(nBands):
  prediction = np.reshape(predicted[:,i], (imageHeight, imageWidth))
  predictedArr[i] = prediction

raster.export(predictedArr, metaData, filename=outFile, dtype='float', bands='all')
```